# C#: Dice Permutation without Repetition

Tags: c#, math, permutation, combinatorics

How can I change my C# code below to list all possible permutations without repetitions?  For example: The result of 2 dice rolls would produce 1,1,2 so that means 2,1,1 should not appear.

Below is my code:

```
string[] Permutate(int input)
{
        string[] dice;
        int numberOfDice = input;
        const int diceFace = 6;
        dice = new string[(int)Math.Pow(diceFace, numberOfDice)];
        int indexNumber = (int)Math.Pow(diceFace, numberOfDice);
        int range = (int)Math.Pow(diceFace, numberOfDice) / 6;

        int diceNumber = 1;
        int counter = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i <= indexNumber; i++)
        {
            if (range != 0)
            {
                dice[i - 1] += diceNumber + " ";
                counter++;
                if (counter == range)
                {
                    counter = 0;
                    diceNumber++;
                }
                if (i == indexNumber)
                {
                    range /= 6;
                    i = 0;
                }
                if (diceNumber == 7)
                {
                    diceNumber = 1;
                }
            }
            Thread.Sleep(1);
        }
        return dice;
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

The simplest possible way I could think of:

```
List<string> dices = new List<string>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
{
    for (int j = i; j <= 6; j++)
    {
        for (int k = j; k <= 6; k++)
        {
            dices.Add(string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", i, j, k));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have written a class to handle common functions for working with the binomial coefficient, which is the type of problem that your problem falls under.  It performs the following tasks:

1. Outputs all the K-indexes in a nice format for any N choose K to a file.  The K-indexes can be substituted with more descriptive strings or letters.  This method makes solving this type of problem quite trivial.
2. Converts the K-indexes to the proper index of an entry in the sorted binomial coefficient table.  This technique is much faster than older published techniques that rely on iteration.  It does this by using a mathematical property inherent in Pascal's Triangle.  My paper talks about this.  I believe I am the first to discover and publish this technique, but I could be wrong.
3. Converts the index in a sorted binomial coefficient table to the corresponding K-indexes.
4. Uses [Mark Dominus](http://blog.plover.com/math/choose.html) method to calculate the binomial coefficient, which is much less likely to overflow and works with larger numbers.
5. The class is written in .NET C# and provides a way to manage the objects related to the problem (if any) by using a generic list.  The constructor of this class takes a bool value called InitTable that when true will create a generic list to hold the objects to be managed.  If this value is false, then it will not create the table.  The table does not need to be created in order to perform the 4 above methods.  Accessor methods are provided to access the table.
6. There is an associated test class which shows how to use the class and its methods.  It has been extensively tested with 2 cases and there are no known bugs.

To read about this class and download the code, see [Tablizing The Binomial Coeffieicent](http://tablizingthebinomialcoeff.wordpress.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I'm bad at math as well, this may or may not be helpful...

**Program.cs**

```
namespace Permutation
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Generating list.");

            var dice = new List<ThreeDice>();

            for (int x = 1; x <= 6; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 1; y <= 6; y++)
                {
                    for (int z = 1; z <= 6; z++)
                    {
                        var die = new ThreeDice(x, y, z);

                        if (dice.Contains(die))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(die + " already exists.");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            dice.Add(die);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine(dice.Count + " permutations generated.");

            foreach (var die in dice)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(die);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

ThreeDice.cs

```
namespace Permutation
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public class ThreeDice : IEquatable<ThreeDice>
    {
        public ThreeDice(int dice1, int dice2, int dice3)
        {
            this.Dice = new int[3];
            this.Dice[0] = dice1;
            this.Dice[1] = dice2;
            this.Dice[2] = dice3;
        }

        public int[] Dice { get; private set; }

        // IEquatable implements this method. List.Contains() will use this method to see if there's a match.
        public bool Equals(ThreeDice other)
        {
            // Get the current dice values into a list.
            var currentDice = new List<int>(this.Dice);

            // Check to see if the same values exist by removing them one by one.
            foreach (int die in other.Dice)
            {
                currentDice.Remove(die);
            }

            // If the list is empty, we have a match.
            return currentDice.Count == 0;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "<" + this.Dice[0] + "," + this.Dice[1] + "," + this.Dice[2] + ">";
        }
    }
}
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The important  part of the question is that you want distinct sets (regardless of order).  So for example, a dice roll of [1, 2, 1] is equal to a dice roll of [1, 1, 2].

I'm sure there are a number of ways to skin this cat, but the first thought that comes to mind is to create a EqualityComparer which will compare the list of dice in the way you want, and then use LINQ with the  `Distinct()` method.

Here is the `EqualityComparer`, which takes 2 `List<int>` and says they are equal if the elements are all equal (regardless of order):

```
    private class ListComparer : EqualityComparer<List<int>>
    {
        public override bool Equals(List<int> x, List<int> y)
        {
            if (x.Count != y.Count)
                return false;
            x.Sort();
            y.Sort();
            for (int i = 0; i < x.Count; i++)
            {
                if (x[i] != y[i])
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
        public override int GetHashCode(List<int> list)
        {
            int hc = 0;
            foreach (var i in list)
                hc ^= i;
            return hc;
        }
    }
```

And here is the code that uses it.  I'm using LINQ to build up the list of all combinations... you could also do this with nested `for` loops but I like this better for some reason:

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        var values = new[] { 1,2,3,4,5,6 };
        var allCombos = from x in values
                        from y in values
                        from z in values
                        select new List<int>{ x, y, z };
        var distinctCombos = allCombos.Distinct(new ListComparer());

        Console.WriteLine("#All combos: {0}", allCombos.Count());
        Console.WriteLine("#Distinct combos: {0}", distinctCombos.Count());
        foreach (var combo in distinctCombos)
            Console.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}", combo[0], combo[1], combo[2]);
    }
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here is generic c# version using recursion (basically the recursive method takes number of dices or number of times the dice has been tossed) and returns all the combinations strings ( for ex, for '3' as per the question - there will be 56 such combinations).

```
public string[] GetDiceCombinations(int noOfDicesOrnoOfTossesOfDice)
        {
            noOfDicesOrnoOfTossesOfDice.Throw("noOfDicesOrnoOfTossesOfDice",
                n => n <= 0);
            List<string> values = new List<string>();
            this.GetDiceCombinations_Recursive(noOfDicesOrnoOfTossesOfDice, 1, "",
                values);
            return values.ToArray();
        }
        private void GetDiceCombinations_Recursive(int size, int index, string currentValue,
            List<string> values)
        {
            if (currentValue.Length == size)
            {
                values.Add(currentValue);
                return;
            }
            for (int i = index; i <= 6; i++)
            {
                this.GetDiceCombinations_Recursive(size, i, currentValue + i, values);
            }
        }
```

**Below are corresponding tests...**

```
[TestMethod]
        public void Dice_Tests()
        {
            int[] cOut = new int[] { 6, 21, 56, 126 };
            for(int i = 1; i<=4; i++)
            {
                var c = this.GetDiceCombinations(i);
                Assert.AreEqual(cOut[i - 1], c.Length);
            }
        }
```